# Send Email via SharePoint REST

Tags: rest, email, outgoing-email

I am trying to send an email via SharePoint rest when a button is pushed in a custom HTML form that I've made within SharePoint.

I was implementing the JS solution found [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/177607/send-emails-via-sharepoint-csom) but this is simply opening up my default mail client instead of automatically sending the email. Is there a way to send the email automatically without opening the default mail client?

```
var mail = {
    properties: {
        __metadata: { 'type': 'SP.Utilities.EmailProperties' },
        From: 'from@mail.com',
        To: { 'results': ['one@mail.com','two@mail.com'] },
        Body: 'some body',
        Subject: 'subject'
    }
};

var getAppWebUrlUrl = decodeURIComponent(utils.getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl").replace("#", ""));
var urlTemplate = getAppWebUrlUrl + "/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail";
$.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: urlTemplate,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(mail),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {

            // code

        },

        error: function (err) {

            // code

        }
    });
```

Comment: Your code is quite right, your problem is not the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is quite right, my guess is that your problem is in the html who calls the method.
HTML

```
<input type="button"id="sendMail" value="Send Email"/>
```

javascript

```
$(function() {
    $("#sendMail").click(function() {
        //var getAppWebUrlUrl = decodeURIComponent(utils.getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl").replace("#", ""));
        var urlTemplate = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +"/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail";
        //your code
    });
});
```

Comment: I am now getting an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: utils is not defined" when the "getAppWebUrlUrl" is being created

Comment: I strongly recommend you to use this property _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl that the site provide.

I edit my answer to help you with this