# _api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail does not work with users without authorization on the current site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, javascript, email

I have the following issue. From JS code in the add-in app (SP online) I am calling the SP Utilities to send an email to users, in the same SP domain obviously (not external accounts).
The function is working correctly only with users who are part of the current group which is operating on the site collection where the add-in is installed. If I try to specify recipients not added in the group they are cut out from the email.
When I try to add the wished user account at the group then it get the email.
But the users are more than 30000 :) I can't add each one.
More over I don't want get them access at the add-in

It is a SP setting? Any idea about??

Thanks in advance

Comment: By design behaviour so an Add-In can not SPAM all users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end I got it. As Sam said: "It will send mail only to those user who are known to site collection..."

I forced the ensuration of each account in the site collection before to send the email.
Below the JSOM code:

```
var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = clientContext.get_web();
//ensure each user
var newUser = web.ensureUser(account);
clientContext.load(newUser);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        function (data) {
            console.log(data)
        },
        function (sender, args) {
            console.log(args.get_message());
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

It is limitation of SharePoint Utility send email function.

It will send mail only to those user who are known to site collection. It means those users who are in User Infoation List which is at site collection and hidden.

Utility.SendMail does not send mail to external users also.

Please check below link for more details.

Link : [Send Emails via SharePoint CSOM](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/177607/send-emails-via-sharepoint-csom)