# SharePoint Online multi line rich text field

Tags: sharepoint-online, rich-text

We have a search webpart which gets the values from 3 lists and displays it in a format on a page. Now when a user click on the ShareMe button. It copies the item description and title and open a email window from outlook with the title and description in subject and body respectively. The body with description doesnt preserve the html i.e the spacing, links etc. Any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with SharePoint.

Section 2 of [RFC 2368](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368) says that the `body` field is supposed to be in `text/plain` format, so you can't do HTML.

However even if you use plain text it's possible that some modern mail clients would render a URL as a clickable link anyway, though.

Reference - [Is it possible to add an HTML link in the body of a MAILTO link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/247395/862892)

There is a workaround for that. You will have to modify your code somewhat as below. Render your HTML in a div and then send the innerHTML.

```
<div id="mailBody"> https://google.com </div>
<input type="button" value="SendMail" onclick="sendMail();">

<script>
function sendMail()
{
   var mailBody=document.getElementById('mailBody').innerHTML;
   window.location="mailto:yourmail@domain.com?subject=testHTMLinmail&body="+mailBody;
}
</script>
```

[W3Schools - tryhtml_link_mailto](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_mailto) - tested the code here and it somewhat works with anchor tags.

However, if it's a full html text and then it would be better to use SPUtility's SendMail method like the solution provided here - [Send Mail using CSOM/REST](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/177611/8068)