# Email Reminder before Due Date using JS/OOB

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow

I have a task to create email reminder based on (30/60/90) days before due date from the list but I can only use OOB wf or clients side script.

NB.
-No SharePoint Designer 
-No Visual Studio allowed ?
Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that is possible. All you have to do is create a calculated column in SharePoint list that will calculate the difference of Due Date from Today and you have to make a check in your Workflow or in Client Side Script on the remaining days. Here is how you can calculate the date difference.

1. Create a new column in  your list, lets say "**Remaining Days**"
2. Apply the below formula to calculate the remaining days from Due Date

`=TEXT(NOW(),"mm/dd/yyyy")-[Due Date]`

[image]

3. Press OK
4. The output will be something like this

[image]

If you can create workflows, you can create check on the **Remaining Days** column if its -30/-60/-90 and then send email. I just wonder how you'll be able to create OOTB Workflows while you said you can't use SharePoint Designer.

You can also send email using general Email Sending method, SharePoint CSOM or SharePoint Rest-API. See [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/177607/send-emails-via-sharepoint-csom) for more details.

Once the number is positive, it means the task is overdue.

**OR**

If you want to see that remaining days in a positive number like 30/60/90 and the overdue days in minus like -30/-60/-90 , just switch the formula with below.

```
=[Due Date]-TEXT(NOW(),"mm/dd/yyyy")
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Muhammad, I am not sure you realise that your answer is flawed for two reasons as far as the question is concerned:
1) You say that it is possible while admitting later on that it is not possible without SP Designer. 2) You cannot use calculated columns for fields that need to change value every day. Calculated fields are updated only when the item is updated, so your formula would give the same number of days tomorrow as it does today unless the item is updated tomorrow as well.

Comment: Yes Mihail i understand your point. But referring to the statement in question "I can only use OOB wf or clients side script." i believed that a JS code can be injected in the page. All i wondered was how they'll create a OOB Workflow without touching SP Designer or Visual Studio. I apologize i did not understand your point number 2.

Comment: OOB workflows ca be added via the *List Settings > Workflow Settings > Add a workflow*. That is what Sara meant. As for point 2 from my comment, I mean that when you have a field like **Remaining Days**, you expect the field's value to be different every passing day until the due date is reached. You cannot use Calculated fields for such a scenario because Calculated fields only update their value when the item is edited. Namely, if you create an item and your formula will give you 30 remaining days today, tomorrow it will still show 30 instead of 29. Try your solution and see that it fails.

Comment: I got your point. I have quickly tried the scenario and found that it worked. However i didn't tried all of the possible scenarios. I'll try that again later and see if it works.

Comment: Yep, the calculated field will work for today, but not tomorrow, **unless** you update the entire item in order to update the value of the field. The calculated field is not a dynamic field, namely it will not display dynamic values regardless what the formula is. The Calculated field is will show a different value only when the item is updated, either via the web interface or programmatically. There are plenty of articles on this problem with calculated fields.

Answer (score 4):

Nope, it is not possible.

If you cannot use SharePoint Designer or Visual Studio to create and publish a workflow to send emails before due dates, then it is not possible.

JavaScript can only be executed when users open up the webpages, and I doubt you have someone who will spend time every day opening up all the items in the list to trigger the JS code.

PowerShell combined with Task Scheduler would work, but then again this is not OOTB.