# Send reminders to those who didn't submit the form/SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, sharepoint-list

I received a new task to implement in SharePoint and I'm not sure if it's possible or not.
We have a SharePoint 2013 list (modified in info Path 2013 to look like a form) and each employee in the company should fill the form.
Is it possible to send reminders or emails to those who didn't submit the form? or at least go a list of all employees who didn't submit yet?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a PowerShell script/app(SSOM or CSOM) to run regularly, in the script(or app), loop the users(suppose a group) and query if user submit the form, if not submit the form, send email to user.

Some object you would use for this requirement for your reference.

CAML query:

[Sample1](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/caml-query-to-retrieve-the-items-from-a-list-using-csom1) and [Sample2](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/caml-query-to-retrieve-the-items-from-a-list-using-csom1)

Send email, check [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/177607/send-emails-via-sharepoint-csom).

Loop group user [sample](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/get-group-users-using-csom1).

Windows task scheduler [sample](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-create-task-basic-task-wizard).

Answer (score 1):

A workflow will not really work for this situation since you need to run it on a schedule.

An alternative solution would be a write a Powershell command that is scheduled to run via the task Scheduler on the local SharePoint Server. Please refer to the articles

[Send scheduled Reminder/Alerts by email in SharePoint](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/32753/send-scheduled-reminder-alerts-by-email-in-sharepo)

[Sending Automatic Notification Reminder Emails to Submit an InfoPath Form to SharePoint Form Library](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/25073609/Sending-Automatic-Notification-Reminder-Emails-to-Submit-an-InfoPath-Form-to-SharePoint-Form-Library.html)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that after each employee fills out the form, it appears as an item in the list created by that employee - is that correct?

If yes - do you have a list of your employees? E.g. as a separate SharePoint list? You could consider creating a list of "Didn't submit employees" by detracting DidSubmit (all creators from the initial list) from All Employees.

Do you want to run it as a SharePoint Workflow? Site/List WF? How should it be triggered? The options here are rather limited: 
[Workflow Triggers](https://www.kalmstrom.com/Tips/SharePoint-Workflows/Workflow-Triggers.htm)
[Clock triggered options](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/dea1087d-a971-4936-9cbb-0ee456aa3270/trigger-a-workflow-when-a-date-is-reached-in-sharepoint-online?forum=sharepointgeneral)

Or do you want to send out the email manually once?

Comment: actually the employees comes from AD not a list.